# Fastest way to filter a collection C#

Tags: c#, search

I've a collection of objects, and I'd like to retrieve all objects that have one of its properties match a search string. So far I've tried a few methods of filtering, namely List.ForAll, IEnumerable.Where, and ParallelQuery.Where.

```
List<Foo> cache = GetAllObjs(); // source list containing lots of objects
```

Option 1:

```
List<Foo> foos = cache.AsParallel().Where(x => x.Name == "bar").ToList();
```

Option 2:

```
List<Foo> foos = cache.Where(x => x.Name == "bar").ToList();
```

Option 3:

```
List<Foo> foos = cache.FindAll(x => x.Name == "bar");
```

Because ParallelQuery.Where utilises multiple cores, it appears to be the fastest solution. Other than these, are there other methods of filtering, such as using different collection types, or filtering functions? The source collection doesn't have to be a List.

Comment: [Race the horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)... it probably depends on the size of the array and other factors

Comment: I did race the horses... The three that I could think of anyway. I was wondering if there were different horses around that I could race instead...

Comment: Its hard to say what the best option (of the given) would be, like I said, for smaller arrays/lists, the spin-up time of the parallel threads might not offer any benefit in terms of execution time. the call to `ToList` might not be necessary either

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Other than these, are there other methods of filtering, such as using different collection types, or filtering functions?

If you can have multiple objects with the same name, you can use a `Lookup<string, Foo>`. You can think of a lookup as a `string -> List<Foo>` dictionary:

```
// create
var foosByName = GetAllObjs().ToLookup(x => x.Name, x => x);

// search
var barFoos = foosByName["bar"].ToList();
```

Of course, if there is only one `Foo` for every name, a classic `Dictionary<string, Foo>` will serve.

Searching in a dictionary or lookup is (usually) an O(1) operation, whereas the search methods in your question are O(n).

Comment: Oh wow I changed to a `Lookup<string, Foo>` and it made the search almost instantaneous. Because I had to do substring matching, as in `x.Name.Contains("bar")`, I had to create a `Lookup` with the index as all the possible substrings of a `Name`. It ate up a lot of memory during the preprosessing stage, but the search itself was lightning fast.

Comment: @painiyff: Glad to hear that. Should you need something with low memory consumption *and* prefix search support, you can [use a trie (sic) or a binary search through a SortedDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1902108/87698).