# Resolving performance Issues on Linq with "LIKE"

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a recognition table containing 25,000 records, and an incoming table of strings that must be recognised using LIKE matching, typically between 200 and 4000 per batch. This used to be in sql server but I am trying to get it to go faster by doing it all in memory, however linq is much slower, taking 5 seconds instead of 250ms in sql when the incoming table has 200 rows.

The recognition table is declared as follows:

```
Private mRecognition377LK As New SortedDictionary(Of String, RecognitionItem)(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

The actual like comparison is here:

```
r = mRecognition377LK.FirstOrDefault(Function(v As KeyValuePair(Of String, RecognitionItem)) sTitle Like v.Key).Value
```

So this is executed for every incoming record and I thought that using v.key would enable the linq engine to not scan records that start with a different character, but it seems not.

I can reinvent the wheel and create a collection class that splits the recognition table into its constituent

E.g. if an incoming string is abcdef and we have a recognition record of "abc*" then I could store collection grouped by length of recognition item up to the first star (3), then inside that a collection of recognition items with that length, keyed on the text up to the first star (abc)

So abc* has a string length of 3 so:

```
r = Itemz(3).Recog("abc")
```

I think that will work and perform well but its a lot of faff and I'm sure that collection classes and linq would have been designed in a way that such a simple thing could be executed quickly without this performance drag.

So my question is is there a way to make this go fast without going to my proposed solution ?

**DRAFT ANSWER**

So having programmed up several iterations of TRIE and binary searches I realised that all this was excessive processing and that is because....

BOTH LISTS ARE SORTED

... that means we only need one loop to process both lists and join them, i.e. we are doing in C#/VB what Sql Server does when it performs a MERGE join. So now I am pursuing this as a solution and will update here as appropriate.

**FINAL UPDATE**

The solution is now finished, and you can indeed join as many lists as you like as long as they are all sorted ascending or all sorted descending on the attributes you are joining, and you can do this in a single loop (because they are sorted). My code is about 1000 lines and very specific, so I'm not going to post a code solution, but for anyone that hits this kind of problem in future, it seems there is nothing in linq that will help do a merge join which is not based on equality (we have LIKE matching) so writing your own merge join in a single loop is possible when the incoming data is sorted.

The basis of the algorithm is to loop through the table which is your "maintable", and advance a pointer into each other list until the text comparison becomes greater than or equal. When its equal, you don't advance this list again until it doesn't match the maintable list, since one item on the right could join many items on the left. This can be repeated for multiple arrays.

It would be nice to see a library where you can pass lambda functions to perform merge joins on multiple sorted arrays. I will consider writing one in future.

The solution runs in 0.007 seconds to join 200 records to a 70,000 record recognition list. With linq performing effectively an inner loop, it took 5 seconds. When joining 4000 records to the same 70,000 record recognition list, the performance degrades only slightly to around 0.01s, showing the great effectiveness of the merge join logic. Sql server took around 250ms to perform the join.

Comment: "by doing it all in memory" why do you think sql server didn't do it in memory?

Comment: Go back to the database server and use proper indexing. The database server has *far* faster CPU, disks and far more RAM than a client machine. It can use indexes that the client doesn't have. If you had perf problems with the database, loading the data in the client will make them far worse

Comment: No we need to add recognition logic that can't be done in sql server, and we need a faster solution than sql not a slower one. Sql server is not an option and anyway we can do without the IO. It should always be possible to equal or beat sql servers performance with in-memory processing.

Comment: @user2728841 but you use 25000 times more IO now. And `It should always be possible to equal or beat sql servers`, no, the exact opposite is true. Why would your quad-core client machine be faster than a 64-core database server? How can 8GB of generic RAM be faster than 128GB of server RAM ?

Comment: _"we need to add recognition logic that can't be done in sql server"_ - what logic to do you need to add that can't be handled by [Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: @user2728841 if you want an answer, explain what you're trying to do and why you think you can't use SQL Server. What you mean by `LIKE` patterns. No `SortedDictionary` is going to help you when you need to scan *all items* to see if they match. That's not LINQ's problem.

Comment: omg I don't want to waste your time arguing about doing it in sql server, just take my word for it that what we need can't be done efficiently. We have to find a way of doing it quickly in C#. And yes all data processing can be done as fast or faster than sql server, otherwise sql server wouldn't be able to do it

Comment: LINQ is not a magic; whenever you do `Where` / `FirstOrDefault`, it just iterates whole collection, so you always have O(N) for _each_ compare. So yes, you need to reinvent the wheel and create logic optimized to your needs if you want to go with client inmemory processing

Comment: @user2728841 if you want an answer, explain what you want. We can't take your work that you can't do it on SQL Server. The code you posted shows *several* problems that have no relation to LINQ. That SortedDictionary is *equivalent* to a single field index. It *can't* accelerate pattern matches, only equality checks. LINQ isn't slow, your code effectively does a `foreach(var txt in dict.Keys)( if (title.Contains(txt))`. You're scanning all 25K items. You could have used `dict.Keys.FirstOrDefault(key=>title.Contains(key))`

Comment: @user2728841 sql server has highly optimized code. You'll need to replicate the logic of an index. I think you should just not talk about SQL Server in your question since it's adding noise to your actual question.

Comment: You can get minor (*minor*) improvements by using a plain-old array instead of a dictionary. Iterating a dictionary is more expensive than iterating an array. You could use a regex instead of `Like`. In SQL Server though you could use a Full Text Search index to perform fast FTS searches.

Comment: You *have* to explain what you want to do. A prefix search for example is essentially a range search, which means it can use indexes in a database or binary search techniques on the client. It can be accelerated a lot using specialized containers like prefix trees/tries. Searching everywhere inside a string though is far more complex.

Comment: actually if all you need is just prefix search, then you need _trie_ as a structure like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1902156/2170171

Comment: If FTS isn't appropriate, perhaps because you want fuzzy matching, you should probably check Elasticsearch. Even if you don't use it, you'll end up using the algorithms it uses, like Levenshtein distance.

Comment: @Lanorkin a prefix search is essentially a `LIKE 'abc%'` in the database and can use indexes. After all it's equivalent to `field>='abc' and field<'abd'`

Comment: Yes indexes are the way to go, so what is built into .NET generics/collections that I could utilise which helps with that ? I have a c++ background and am able to solve this problem from first principles, but I would prefer to use something built in if it exists.